# Fake Entity Framework queries while waiting for DBA to make changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

We have a Web API front-end and a business layer that has service objects which contain Entity Framework Linq-to-Entities. We are using Code-First, but we are not generating the database. Instead, we are using the EF Reverse POCO generator.

We have two on-going problems which are both related to having to wait for our DBA to finish their work on the tables. The first problem is that the table structure isn't complete for us to generate the POCOs, and the second problem is not having data in the new table or column.

**Is there an easy way to fake the structure and/or data so we can finish our Linq-to-entity queries?** My first thought was to generate the POCOs as partials and temporarily add the properties to a non-generated partial class. Then for fake data, I was wondering if there was a way to intercept the Linq query and return fake data until the DB changes are complete, then we'd remove the interceptor. Is this possible? Or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: Haven't you got a dev database?

Comment: @GertArnold, yes, but the DBA is the one who is doing the development on it.

Comment: Sigh....  I think as a developer you should have a database that you can modify any time, preferably on your local machine. Let the DBA review proposed changes. Make them part of the development team. Any alternative, using command interceptors for example, is an incredible over-engineered solution to an organizational problem.

Comment: You could create a clone db and change the connection string to point to this clone.

Answer (score 0):

So you are basically asking how to provide a mocked up DbSet with mocked up entities. It is possible, since it is in effect what you do to be able to unit test methods using EF6.

The summary, before I go into details:
* install the Moq nuget package.
* Create a helper method that can take an entity and return a mocked DbSet of that entity.

```
private static Mock<DbSet<T>> CreateDbSetMock<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements) where T : class
{
  var elementsAsQueryable = elements.AsQueryable();
  var dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();

  dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.Provider);
  dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.Expression);
  dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.ElementType);
  dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.GetEnumerator());

  mockSet.Setup(t => t.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>(data.Add);
  mockSet.Setup(t => t.Remove(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>(t => data.Remove(t));

  return dbSetMock;
}
```

Then create your new entities and create the mocked DbSet this way.
    var dbSet = CreateDbSetMock(new List());

Add your data just like you would expect.
    dbSet.Add(new NewEntity{somedata});

Then query the data just like you would expect,
    dbSet.Where(some logic).FirstOrDefault();

If you were using EF Core, I'd tell you just to use the In Memory Provider, the above code only works for EF 6 as far as I am aware.